# GPS Position Updates more accurate after opening Google Maps?

Tags: ios, google-maps, gps

I'm having a strange problem.  I have an app which uses GPS for location based updates to a map that is displayed.  I'm finding that the GPS accuracy is poor within the application, but if I open Google Maps and then go back into my app, the accuracy is spot on.

Any ideas?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
      didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
double lat;
double lng;
lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
lng = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

//Other stuff that uses the location
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask for a specific accuracy when you create your location manager like this :

```
[manager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
```

See the [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/kCLLocationAccuracyBest).

Comment: Took a while to get user feedback, but that seems to have done it.  Thanks!